Interchanging a partial limit and integration
I have the limit of an integral
$$ I = \lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}  \int_A dx \ f(x,y)$$
where $A$ is some compact segment.
On wikipedia, I see the dominated convergence theorem allows me to bring the limit inside if $|f(x,y)|\le g(x) \ ,  \quad \forall \ y\rightarrow \infty, \ x\in A$, where $g(x)$ is some function integrable on $A$. To my physicist brain, that essentially means that if $f(x,y)$ is integrable for finite $y$ approaching the limit and for `$y=\infty$', then it's ok.
(Apologies if I said something inaccurate so far, it shouldn't affect the following question). Now suppose $f(x,y)$ does not satisfy the conditions for bringing the limit inside. But suppose it is the product of two functions
$f(x,y)=f_1(x,y)f_2(x,y)$. My question is, is it possible to take the limit 'partially inside' to act on only $f_2$ as long as the integrand satisfies the condition above for this partial limit. Explicitly, can I say
$$ I = \lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}  \int_A dx \ f_1(x,y) \left(\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty}f_2(x,z)\right)  $$
if the integrand is integrable for all finite $z$ approaching the limit
and `$z=\infty$'?

What does $d^2x$ mean? If it is double integral it would be better to write $dx dy$.

Originally it was a double integral, but it shouldn't matter so I changed it to a single integral. y is not being integrated over.

In general, the answer is no. Even the choice $f_1 \equiv 1$ shows that not all the decomposition would make the equality happen, and I think it is extremely hard, if not impossible, to answer your question.

And let me give my understanding on interchanging the order of limit and integral.
First, DCT can be interpreted as "mass confinement condition" in the following sense: Restricting ourselves to non-negative $f$ and interpreting $f$ as "density", an application of Fatou's lemma tells that
$$\int_{A}\lim_{y\to\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,f(x,y)
\quad\leq\quad
\lim_{y\to\infty}\int_{A}\mathrm{d}x\,f(x,y)$$
whenever both sides exist. In other words, when you bring the limit into the integral sign, you generally lose some of mass. This loss of mass can occur in two ways:

Some of the mass become so concentrated that it cannot be captured in macroscopic level. For example, $f(x, y) = y \cdot \mathbf{1}[0 < x < 1/y]$ satisfies
$$ \lim_{y \to \infty} \int_{[0, 1]} \mathrm{d}x \, f(x, y) = 1\qquad \text{but}\qquad \lim_{y \to \infty} f(x, y) = 0 \quad\text{for all $x$}.$$
Below is the graph of $f(\cdot, y)$ as $y$ growssrc)

And we already know that $f(x, y)$ converges to the Dirac delta $\delta(x)$ as $y\to\infty$ in some sense (such as in distribution sense or in weak convergence of measures). Since $\delta(x)$ describes concentration of a unit mass at a microscopic region, it slips away from the grip of pointwise limit.

Some of mass is washed away toward "infinity". For example, $f(x, y) = \frac{1}{2y} \mathbf{1}[|x| \leq y]$ satisfies
$$ \lim_{y \to \infty} \int_{[0, 1]} \mathrm{d}x \, f(x, y) = 1\qquad \text{but}\qquad \lim_{y \to \infty} f(x, y) = 0 \quad\text{for all $x$}.$$
Below is the graph of $f(\cdot, y)$ as $y$ growssrc)

As the formula suggests, the mass comprising $f(\cdot, y)$ becomes more dispersed as $y$ grows, essentially escaping any finite region in the limit.


Now DCT is designed to prevent these from happening by confining all the density functions $f(\cdot, y)$ in the finite region $\{(x, y) : |y| \leq g(x)\}$. Below image demonstrates an example of $f(x, y)$ as a function of $x$, which is bounded by $\pm g(x)$ and converges as $y\to\infty$:src)

Although DCT is good enough in many applications, still it is only a sufficient condition and do not cover all the cases in which mass is conserved (hence the limit can be interchanged with the integral). In such case, one has to work with case by case.

Thank you for your answer. While I digest it in full, let me reply to your first sentence and clarify. Of course $f_1=1$ does not work. On the other hand, $f_2=1$ works trivially. I guess my question is precisely, under what conditions can I apply the limit to just one factor of the integrand, before integration.
